# Persistent notification of running app on Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Since upgrading to Android 4.3, my application is displaying a persistent system notification:

[image: [My App] is running; Touch for more information or to stop the app]

It reads:

> **[My App] is running**
>   Touch for more information or to stop the app

Why is it there, and what can I do about it?

Comment: check my possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18281520/444324 May work for you if you still want to hide the notification itself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior [is triggered by applications (ab)using `Service.startForeground()`](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/MTinJWdNL8t).

The idea behind using [`startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) is that you provide a notification through which users can interact with your app while it is running. For instance, if it's a music player, make sure you're providing the persistent notification as a parameter of the function, so that Android knows the user already has a way of letting your app invoke `stopForeground()`.

You can basically see this as "public shaming", because apps should behave nicely on the platform and let the system kill them if it needs to.

(In my case, the culprit was actually Robospice; [here's the line](http://octo-online.github.io/robospice/site/latest/xref/com/octo/android/robospice/SpiceService.html#360) in question and [the associated issue](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/issues/170).)

Comment: Totally right, an android Engineer says the same thing here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/29/android-engineer-explains-why-some-apps-suddenly-have-persistent-notifications-after-you-upgrade-to-android-4-3/

Comment: Hello Paul, once more I find your answer here rather than asking directly ) thnx it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you **device is rooted** you can hide these notifications using [GravityBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-4-tweak-box-android-t2316070) using the Xposed Framework.

In GravityBox go to `Statusbar tweaks >> Ongoing notification blocker >> Select which to block >> Ok` After a device reboot those notifications will be gone.