# Is it possible to create a Notification which doesn't generate Heads up Notification, but will appear in lock-screen

Tags: android, notifications, heads-up-notifications

I am currently in a project which develops a DECT-based android system based on Android 5.0.1, and need to add a mode which will bring up the Dialer App while the InCallUi App is running (when there is an incoming call). When the Dialer App is in the foreground, there will be an annoying headsup notification from the InCallUi App showing the incoming call information displaying on the top of the screen.

I want to ask if there is a way to hide the headsup notification, while in locked-screen the notification entry can still be seen?

I have tried to change the priority of the notification, as indicated in the following link that the headsup notification only presented when the priority is set to HIGH, MAX and FULL_SCREEN: "If a notification's priority is flagged as High, Max, or full-screen, it gets a peeking notification.", but when I set the priority to LOW or MIN the headsup notification still shows:
https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior

Can anyone help? thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this was a security bridge on older versions of android that provided a way to `services` to run as `ForegroundServices` without the user knowing, that issue was fixed in android 4.4.
You can see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Nir Duan, but in some circumstances hiding the heads-up notification is really needed, hope that android can provide something like a priority level or a flag which can solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know what your use-case is, but in my experience you can mostly find workaround.