# Android: Sticky vs Foreground Service vs Alternative

Tags: java, android, background

I have an Android Application that uses a Countdown Timer that lasts for around 2 days. What is the best method to avoid my Countdown Timer from being killed by the Android Application Manager even if the user enables a power saving mode or restarts their phone ? (Sorry if this is a senseless question to answer, for the reason that I am new to Android development.)

Comment: Do you know what the options are? have you tried anything?

Comment: @CallumDA33, I have tried the foreground service but  it got killed after the device restarted at first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup, note that if you want a foreground service you must have a notification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best method to avoid my Countdown Timer from being killed by the Android Application Manager even if the user enables a power saving mode or restarts their phone ?

That is not possible. Moreover, it is very wasteful (tying up system RAM, spending CPU time). If you want to get control at a certain time in the future, use methods on `AlarmManager` (e.g., `setAlarmClock()`). If you want to find out how much time remains between now and that certain time in the future, find out the current time (e.g., `System.currentTimeMillis()`) and subtract that from the future time to calculate the difference in times. To handle a reboot, you would need to set up the `AlarmManager` again, by using a `BroadcastReceiver` set up to respond to `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Comment: Thank you very much, would I need to create a database to save  the current time and future time so  it can be accessible after the reboot because I'm really bad at seeing up databases

Comment: @K.Milli: You would not need to save the current time, as the current time is always available from the system. You need to save the future time in persistent storage for any solution if you want that data to exist after a reboot.

Comment: Sorry, hopefully this is   last question— do you possibly have a resource of how I can incorporate the Alarm Manager and BroadcastReceiver to update my GUI? Because I need to display the days, hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: @K.Milli: While your activity is around, feel free to use something like `CountDownTimer` for that. The vast majority of the time, the user is not in your UI, and you will not have a process running. In those cases, if you want to get control when the future time arrives, *that* is what `AlarmManager` is for.

Comment: I get it! Thank you so much!

Comment: #mostNicestPersonOnStackOverflow