# Have service running when app is closed from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service

I want to keep running one service which reads incoming messages even after app is closed [clicking on recent apps button and then close it]. I have tried using START_STICKY, isolated process but nothing is working. Is it possible in latest android versions ?

Comment: You can run your service in a separate process.

Comment: I tried doing that my putting process name and isolated as true, but app gets killd.

Comment: If your service onstartcommand return START_STICKY, than if application process got killed it will restart service again.
Check here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: @ Christopher Running service in separate process with not work, as it will get terminated once application process is killed.

Comment: START_STICKY doesn't work.

Comment: I am killing app by clicking on recent apps icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try `startForeground(notitficationId, notificationObject);` command in `onStartCommand()`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startForground(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentText("App Name")
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

If you don't want to show notification or icon but still want to run in background try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404905/2102794)

Comment: I don't want to show any icon. Want to run this as a background service.

Answer (score 0):

Making a sticky service, will ensure you restarting after app is closed, but you need to call your methods in `onStartComand()`.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // do your job here
    // start reading your incoming messages
    readMessages();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: START_STICKY doesn't work. Service gets killed when i swipe it from recent used apps.

Comment: Yes, but should start after is killed. You can't keep a service running all the time.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
..........

return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

but when you close the application onStartCommand restart from the beginning whether it has finished it's job or not!