# Android how to hide the "ApplicationName Is running the background"

Tags: android

I created an app that replaces the lockscreen, I've used https://github.com/Kirk-Str/LockScreenApp as an example of how to do it, the problem is there is a notification that the app is running in the background

How can i hide this message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964250/5906447

Comment: When running a `Service` in the background the system notifies the user that the app is running in the background. This is by default in devices that runs Oreo.. Your only 2 options are: 1) Don't run a service in the background. 2) Show an ongoing notification while the service is running (Run it as a Foreground service)

Comment: So is there a way for me to make a custom lock screen without a service?@HedShafran @Sahil

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Its possible to run certain background tasks/jobs that are outside the scope of a Service.

Comment: @JeremyRempel my application simply replaces the lock screen and enables 2 pin codes instead of one, one of them does additional functions one simply opens the phone