# Start service without showing no notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have created a service for calculating Steps. Obviously it will be running in background always . So I used startForground(1, notification) method.
But I don't want to show notification as it is very irritating for users as they are keep telling. I want to remove it.
I tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification) to achieve it, but no gain.
Is there any trick ??

Comment: The link you have posted says clearly "As a security feature of the Android platform, you cannot, under any circumstance, have a foregrounded service without also having a notification"

Comment: fortunately you cannot do it: i wouldn't like dozens of foreground services running without my knowledge...

Comment: It might be possible to reduce the annoyance by providing a better notification? For example, my media player notification doesn't annoy me because it shows the album art, current track, play/pause buttons and forward/rewind buttons. It is useful and informative...

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) and link you have shared yourself, you cannot achieve this due to obvious **security** reasons.

And as you mentioned you are creating service for **calculating Steps**, You may need to use **Location Service** in background as well, So as per [Android Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits),

> The system distinguishes between foreground and background apps. An app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:
>   It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
>   It has a foreground service.

You have to use **Foreground Service with Notification** as to tell user your app is receiving location updates.

So in nutshell Foreground Service without notification **cannot be achieved**