# How to show notification badge count on Android 10+ devices?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, badge, android-launcher

How can we show notification count in Android on Home screen app launcher icon with count and how to increment and decrement this count? And if we want to increase count with silent push means without showing notification in app bar then can we achieve this functionality too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial of how to implement the notification count badges on app launcher icon: [How to display count of notifications in Android app launcher icon?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-android-app-launcher-icon)

And to answer this part of the question:

> And if we want to increase count with silent push means without showing notification in app bar then can we achieve this functionality too?

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve that because it is against Google policy for background services restrictions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964250/5973063

Comment: I've implemented this solution but this is showing only badge without any count, I want to show counts and neither increasing nor decreasing and also not able to remove this badge

Comment: @AmmyKang the user's launcher needs to support showing badge numbers, not all do.  Now days most launchers just show a dot, if they shot anything at all.