# Android Workmanager, expedited work show notification even if app is already in foreground

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Using the Setexpedited() function in Workmanager ( 2.7 >), is useful to start a persistent work that last even if the user close the app and/or put it in background.

The problem is that it needs to show a notification everytime the work starts, even when the app is already active and in foreground, so a notification should not be necessary.

Is there a way to avoid workmanager/setexpedited to show the notification if the app is in foreground?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running

**Under the hood, WorkManager manages and runs a foreground service on your behalf to execute the WorkRequest, while also showing a configurable notification.**

The short answer is "NO". What you have in that case(what WorkManager is using under the hood) is a ForegroundService:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Here is a question about removing the notification of a ForegroundService:

[How to startForeground() without showing notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification)

From the top answer:

**However, it is possible to have a "fake" notification, i.e., you can make a transparent notification icon (iirc). This is extremely disingenuous to your users, and you have no reason to do it, other than killing their battery and thus creating malware.**

Comment: I do not want to remove the notification from a foreground service. Consider an app with a simple button, when the user tap the button some "work" starts. I need this work to continue, if needed, even if the user then leave/close the app. The best way is to use an expedited work with WorkManager. I'm OK in showing the notification if the work re-start (retry), when the app is not in foreground anymore, but why I have to show a notification to the user everytime he taps the button? Is this avoidable?

Comment: @Bofaquien because the WorkManager is using a ForegroundService

Comment: Yep, that is clear, also a nonsense, when the user tap a button the app is in already running a foreground process, workmanager should use it, and run a different foreground service if the app is in background/closed, that is when the notification makes sense to alert the user that a sleeping app is doing something under the hood. Hope Google is going to correct this in a later feature.