How to Run a Foreground Service Without a Persistent Notification in Flutter?
I am working on a Flutter project where I need to run a background service that continuously sends location updates. I'm using the flutter_background_service package to achieve this. However, I want to avoid showing a persistent notification when the service is running in the foreground.
What I've Tried:
Running the Service in Background Mode:
I configured the service with isForegroundMode: false to avoid the notification, but this causes the service to be stopped by the Android system when the app goes into the background.
await service.configure(
  androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
    onStart: onStart,
    autoStart: true,
    isForegroundMode: false,  // No notification, but the service may be killed by the system
  ),
  iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
    autoStart: true,
    onForeground: onStart,
    onBackground: onIosBackground,
  ),
);

Using a Low-Importance Notification:
I tried setting up a notification with Importance.min, hoping it would be less visible, but the notification is still displayed.
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'low_importance_channel',
  'Low Importance Notifications',
  description: 'This channel is used for low importance notifications',
  importance: Importance.min,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  const InitializationSettings(
    android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_bg_service_small'),
  ),
);

Despite my efforts, the notification still shows up when the service is running in the foreground. I need the service to run continuously in the background or foreground without displaying a persistent notification.

Not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964250/14071053   . But, If you blocked the notification from system settings then it can work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177817/14071053
