# Android threads timeout

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i have an asynctask that sends out the location of the android device once every one second when the application starts and keeps doing so until the application is destroyed to a server...

my problem is for some reason after some time even though internet is still available and wasn't interrupted, and even though the server didn't crash and was operational at all time, the phone stops sending out the location, my question is.... is there a timeout on running threads in android that shuts down a running thread or task after sometime? if so how to get rid of it or extend the time? if not what could be the problem?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out if the system goes low on memory it kills background processes this can be avoided by using startForeground instead check "[Android - implementing startForeground for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)"