# How to implement startforeground without the deprecated Notification class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I got how to implement the startforeground deom this thread [Android - implementing startForeground for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)

And this works also, but the Notification is mentioned as deprecated, how to implement this with the new one ?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. The solution is quite simple though.

Use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` to create the Notification, as only the Notification constructor is deprecated not the whole class.

Example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat
        .Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setContentTitle("Updating...");
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```