# Show ongoing notifications in Android Wear

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I've been playing around with Android Wear and making some dummy apps. What I've noticed is that Android Wear doesn't seem to show the notifications that are ongoing,i.e., notifications with `setOngoing(true)`. 
Any way to show these notifications on Wear???

Comment: I don't think an ongoing notification that cannot be cancelled would be functional on Android wear. Notifications, in a way, on the wear serves as apps. How irritating is a app that doesn't want to close? If you want to do this I think you would have to use the update feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On-going notifications will not show up on Wearable devices. Instead you have to implement a [Wear App](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html) on the wearable and show cards from there.

Answer (score 13):

barkside's answer is correct. I recently wrote an article describing the steps in details, but basically:

1. Create a wearable app with a service implementing WearableListenerService.
2. Send a data item from the handheld app using the Data API.
3. In the wearable app's service, handle receiving the data item & build an ongoing notification upon receipt.

A sample app is available here:
https://github.com/doubleencore/WearOngoingNotificationSample

And step-by-step directions are available here:
http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/07/create-custom-ongoing-notification-android-wear/

Answer (score 3):

Our notifications show up with `setOngoing(true)` and `Service.startForeground` but they didn't on the first day the SDK was out, might've been an update to the Android Wear Preview app?

Comment: So... I have the same problem now, my ongoing notification just doesn't appear with startForeground... Did it start working for you by any chance @d3m0li5h3r ?

Comment: I just posted a related question in the G+ community. Waiting for someone from the team to reply... https://plus.google.com/+BenoitBoDLubek/posts/4we2mWEo8vy

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet "playing" with Android Wear SDK, but I guess that if there is a way to make ongoing undismissable notifications - it should be in conjuction with the [`Service.startForeground()` Service method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service).    exactly like it works with the hosting android device...

Answer (score 0):

If you using `service` to play music, Wear takes notification from `RemoteControlClientCompat` and keep it ongoing while music is playing. It will looks like Play Music does.