# Notification does not work properly on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I use a service for background work(send data to server) when my app is in the background.So I create a notification which tells to the user that app is running in the background.I want when the user taps on the notification my app to come to the foreground so I use an Intent like this that android use to launch my app

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.final_driver_notification_icon)
   .setContentTitle("...")
   .setContentText("...");

    final Intent notintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EntryScreen.class);

    notintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    notintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent pendint = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notintent, 0);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendint);

    int notID = 001;


    startForeground(notID, mBuilder.build());
```

In the emulator and some physical devices works perfect.But in some other it launches the app from the start(It puts Entry screen in the top).
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: It could be because the activity was maybe killed by android to increase resource. I'm not sure though. You should put a log in onDestroy and check if that ever executes.

Comment: No onDestroy isn't called!And my activity that running right before app goes to background is still active because when i press back after app launch from notification i can see it.In some devices this Intent puts EntryScreen in the top of the stack but when press app icon it works perfect!It brings app foreground without starting a new instance of EntryScreen!

Comment: i think you should remove this line " notintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);". It will always start your launcher screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your service with startForeground(). this is the way to start a service in foreground and report by a notification. [Android - implementing startForeground for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)

or try something like this:

```
public void initForeground() {
        Intent intentForeground = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        intentForeground.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentForeground,0);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentForeground,0);          

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.something))
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.something))
                .setAutoCancel(false);    

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

        startForeground(myID, notification);
    }
```

Hope it helps you!