# Unable to Restart Service after killed despite running in foreground and with START_STICKY

Tags: android, service, bind, persistent, foreground-service

I am facing a critical issue with binded service running as foreground and with notification. I am doing everything correct as mentioned by most of the tutorials and solutions I found. I have an activity which starts a service and then bind with it. In onCreate() of service, i am using startForeground() and showing notification as well. I am also returning START_STICKY in onStartCommand() but when my application gets killed i see this in my log cat ..

```
Force stopping package com.example.voicerecognizersp appid=10102 user=0
I/ActivityManager(  929): Killing proc 27176:com.example.voicerecognizersp/u0a10102: force stop com.example.voicerecognizersp
W/ActivityManager(  929): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.voicerecognizersp/.RecordingMfccService in 5000ms
I/ActivityManager(  929):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{453068e0 u0 com.example.voicerecognizersp/.RecordingMfccService}
```

Service is trying to restart but gets force stopped. I want service to restart if app gets killed for any reason. I know its a binded service and runs in the same process as activity but to fix it, i am already calling startService before bind and using foreground to reduce max chances of getting killed. Can anyone explain still why service gets force stopped when its trying to restart ?

My main chunk of Service class looks like this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
    runAsForeground();


}


/**
 * Show a notification while this service is running and run as foreground so
 * that OS knows that Activity depends on service and service is not a candidate
 * to be killed
 */
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/28144499/1016544
private void runAsForeground() {


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainBindingActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,  notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle("VoiceRecognizerSP")
                                .setContentText("Service is running ...")//.build();
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION, notification);

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int rc = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i("LocalService", "onStartCommand Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent + "rc : " + rc );
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
    //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;



}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    // Cancel the persistent notification.
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);

    Log.d(TAG, "Service onDestroy() called");

}




/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    RecordingMfccService getService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getService done");

        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return RecordingMfccService.this;
    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind called");

    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRebind called");
    super.onRebind(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind called");

    return true; //to make sure next time onRebind is called
}
```

I am starting service and binding in onCreate() of Activity

```
if(!isMyServiceRunning())
        {
            startService(new Intent(this,RecordingMfccService.class));
        }


        boolean result = bindService(new Intent(this, RecordingMfccService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver), new IntentFilter(RecordingMfccService.COPA_RESULT));

        if(!result)
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to bind with service in onCreate");
```

and unbinding in onDestroy()

```
if (isBound ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unbind called");

            unbindService(mConnection);
            isBound = false;
            //Log.i(TAG, "onStopRecording Service unbinded & isbound : " + isBound);
            //needToBind = true;

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);



        }
```

Comment: The same here, did you find an answer?

Comment: @SandroSimas It's quite an old answer and I had to go through my logs to find out what were the things I did to fix that problems. I am just listing down the improvements and you can then see which one makes sense for you.

1) Adding Context.BIND_IMPORTANT bumps your process priority one notch higher when the Activity is in the foreground.

2) binding in onCreate and unbinding in onDestroy is important. 

3) Using ThreadPoolExecutor provided by SDK

4) Look for memory leaks. Perform critical operations in a separate thread.