# Android notification, WITHOUT NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a notification, without using the `NotificationCompat.Builder`. The motivation is not using the Support Library if its not really needed (and also for educational purposes)
I assume that its possible, as there are "native" [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) and [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) classes that are exposed to the users.

My try goes as follow:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.SomeActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);


notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, content,pi);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
```

This code just run, but no notification appears, and `notificationManager.notify()` in general returns `void`.

Comment: How do you fill the notification object ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, finally found it -- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62640484/210342