# Can't get location on android studio on real phone

Tags: java, android

I try to get my location on Android Studio but I cant do it on my real phone.

When I click button,my APP would crash.

But I can get virtual location on Emulator.

I already try lot of things like this solution
:[Can't get location on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178945/cant-get-location-on-android-studio)
and
[I can't get location on Android real phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577584/i-cant-get-location-on-android-real-phone)

This is my code:

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String commandStr;

    public static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 11;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        commandStr = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE)
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
    }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(commandStr, 1000, 0, locationListener);
                Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(commandStr);
                if(location!=null)
                    textView.setText("Longitude" + location.getLongitude() + "\n" + "getLatitude" + location.getLatitude());
                else
                    textView.setText("locating...");

}
        });
    }
    public LocationListener locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
           textView.setText("Longitude" + location.getLongitude() + "\n" + "getLatitude" + location.getLatitude());

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

} ```
````

Comment: you describe that "you can't do it on your real phone". What is the error, what happens, nd what would you expect to happen.

Comment: when I click the button to get location,my app crash

Comment: but it can work on  emulator.