# Application starts new service when app is closed

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android app with service that has to track user's location even with closed application only if user set flag in app. So I start service in code after user clicks button and stop when he clicks it again with following code

```
alarm.changeAlarmStatus();
            if(alarm.getAlarmStatus()) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = alarmPreferences.edit();
                ed.putFloat("MARKER_LATITUDE", (float) theMarker.getPosition().latitude);
                ed.putFloat("MARKER_LONGITUDE", (float) theMarker.getPosition().longitude);
                ed.commit();
                startService(myIntent);
            }
            else{
                stopService(myIntent);
            }
```

It seems to work fine. Service works and does what it should. But problem is if I close application through the task manager I see in logcat that Service starts again(but only if service is already working) and it causes nullPointerException because intent is null. You can see in this code why it happens

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    alarm = (Alarm) bundle.getSerializable("alarm");
    Log.d("service","On Start Command is called ");
    serviceIntent = intent;
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

However I need to start my service only by pressing button and no other way. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return [START_NOT_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) in onStartCommand instead of [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

If START_STICKY is returned, system will try to re-create service after it is killed.

If START_NOT_STICKY is returned, system will **not** try to re-create service after it is killed.

Comment: Okay, so it means system kills my service when I kill process. But I need it to work even if application is closed. Can I do that somehow?

Comment: You can achieve that by starting service with startForeground(). [Link to similar question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)