# Start Service on Oreo

Tags: android-studio, service

I use this syntax for starting service on Android Oreo but Google play keep reporting that syntax affects ANR (Appklication Not Responding) on Oreo.

[Report from Google Play Console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruROB.png)

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, new Intent(context, SocketService.class));
```

Help me solve this problem, thanks.

what is the correct way to start the service on oreo?

Comment: call `startForeground (int id, Notification notification)` in onStartCommand.  refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397982/7094064