# Keep a method running even when my app is fully closed (not just sent to background)

Tags: android, service, ondestroy

I am building an app, in which i am displaying some data which i am getting from some url using asynctask & i am updating the data after every 5 seconds using handler and runnable and i am playing a sound every after 5 seconds after receiving data. it is working fine.
Now i want that, when i close the app, it should keep receiving data and play that sound when new data is recieved. 
How can i do that ? I have found that i have to use service for that, but not getting any clear solution, i am very new to android, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a foreground service

Comment: ok,, it will be helpful if you provide some sample code ...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startService()` method in your activity.
And you should create your `Service` in which call `startForeground()` method to prevent the system from closing the service. When in service you may do periodic tasks.
For detailed explanation please visit [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/) page.