# Getting ui freezed when parsing data using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Getting data after 5-6 seconds but till that ui is freezed.

I searched for issue but didn't get proper solution.

How to do this with **parseNetworkResponse**  , Here i am using MVP pattern in my project, so please give me easy solution to implement.

```
public void sendData(final String url, final Map sendData,  final VolleyStringListener volleyStringListener)
    {
     Log.i(TAG,"Sending and receiving data....................................");
        Log.i(TAG,"Used Url = "+url);

        try
        {

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response)
                        {
                            volleyStringListener.onVolleySuccessResponse(response);
                        }
                    },

                        new Response.ErrorListener()
                        {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            volleyStringListener.onVolleyErrorResponse(error);
                        }
                    })

                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                        {
                            return sendData;
                        }
                    };

            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            myVolleySingleton.addToRequestQueue(request);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Write your code in asynctask it will run in a background thread

Comment: any example code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service check this