# How can I show a notification to user from a background running service in android?

Tags: android

Here is my project structure...

[image]

Let me tell you how it works. When I open app it creates a never ending background service namely "**Exampleservice**". This service executes a **async** class "**firebaseOp**" The job of **"firebaseOp"** is to get data from "**Member**" class methods and post it to database.

**Now** after database operation is completed, I want to show a notification to user.

The keypoint here is the app will be close after starting the service and service will run in background. The service is running fine and doing the job but the **How can I show that notification?**

I have tried some codes but getting null object reference error.

Here is the **ExampleService** class (if needed) ....

```
package com.example.btc;

import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleService extends Service {


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service STARTING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


          Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                            firebaseOp Op = new firebaseOp();
                            Op.execute();

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

            };





};
            thread.start();
            return START_STICKY;

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // We don't provide binding, so return null
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at this question [Notification with foreground service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6397754/7948109)

Comment: @RahulGaur I want background  service  buddy.

Comment: System will kill your background service if it needs memory, if you want to show notification continuously I recommend using foreground service

Answer (score 0):

These codes are about showing notifications.Add it where it is needed.

```
Notification.Builder builder =new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent push =new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,push,0);
builder.setContentTitle("My notification")
       .setContentText("Hello World!")
       .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
       .setTicker("New message")
       .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher))
       .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       Notification notify = builder.build();
       mNotifyMgr.notify(1,notify);
```

Comment: error: can't  create handler inside thread that had not called looper.looper