# How to keep using onSensorChanged() when phone asleep?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating an application that needs to detect the biggest acceleration that the phone detects. Currently it works, but it does not continue the task when the screen turns off. To achieve what I have now, I wrote in `onCreate`:

```kotlin
mSensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)
```

I have initialized these variables globally in the class. I then have implemented `onSensorChanged()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()` and left `onAccuracyChanged` empty.

From what I have understood implementing functions like this is different than more simply creating an asynchronous task. How would I go about changing this so to make it work in the background as well? Thank you!

Comment: At best, you would need to implement a foreground service (to help keep your process running) with a partial `WakeLock` (to try to keep the phone CPU awake). Most likely you will also need the phone to be plugged in all the time, as otherwise Doze mode will interrupt your `WakeLock` and allow the CPU to stop. And, even with all of that, it will depend on whether the device manufacturer supports your desired sensors with the screen off -- that is not guaranteed.

Comment: What would a rough example of that be? The app should work without having to be plugged all the time too. Thank you.

Comment: "The app should work without having to be plugged all the time too" -- then I suspect that what you want is not possible across a wide range of Android devices. Some devices have the ability to react to sensor input even when the phone is asleep, but that capability is on a model-by-model basis (and even there, it might be only some sensors, not all) and is not necessarily exposed to app developers.

Comment: That's strange, thank you. I will search more to hopefully find a way to make this work at least on the models where it's possible.

Comment: A notification is a foreground job. Make it persist though. And using a WakeLock too might help,  I think.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Darkman. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the Sensors API when the app went to the background even with `WakeLock` - the [official documentation is clear](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#only-gather-sensor-data-in-the-foreground) about that.

You can easily proceed with using Sensors API even with the phone screen disabled inside a foreground service, though. In order to do that use this documentation as a start - [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). This doesn't guarantee the eternal live of the Service but it will most definitely live longer than an ordinary Service as well as you will have the access to the Sensors API. I am not sure about `WakeLock` in this case - you will have to try(but I think you won't need it).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service) is a span of answers. Some of them contain sample code and even links to sample projects

[Here](https://medium.com/@jayd1992/foreground-services-in-android-e131a863a33d) and [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/what-is-foreground-service-in-android-3487d9719ab6) there are neet examples in form of medium articles.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try it with a foreground task. I’d like to reward the 50 rep to this answer, could you show a quick example of starting a foreground task and running an activity there?

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis not foreground task, but Foreground Service and you cannot run an Activity there - you can run some code there. I will add a few links to some sample code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.