# How can i enter in my application through notification?

Tags: android, onclick, android-activity, android-notifications

This is the code of my notification. I want that onClick my application starts. Right now nothing happen

```
private void CheckNoti(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                service.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   }
```

This is a code inside a class. It's not inside the MainActivity. So i can't do something like:

```
intent.setClassName("your.package.name", "ActivityToLaunch");
```

i think because i already doing `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);`

Comment: why dont you start the activity and then start the service in the activity? It would make more sense to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

To bring your app to the foreground if it is running already you need to set different flags on your intent:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

For running a specific method you could just pass extra information along with the intent and interpret it in your application to decide which method to run.

[See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378193/android-how-to-avoid-that-clicking-on-a-notification-calls-oncreate)